# Was Mary given a glorified or "spiritual body" like the resurrected body of Jesus while on earth?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, resurrection-body, human-body

In the 4th Dogma of Assumption Mary was assumed "body & soul" into heaven.

Scriptures tells us nothing defiled shall enter the Kingdom of God...(Rev21:27)

And also Gospel of Luke 24:36-ff narrates and describes the "resurrected body" of Jesus.

Jesus Appears to the Disciples

> 36 While they were still talking about this, Jesus himself stood among them and said to them, “Peace be with you.”
>
> 37 They were startled and frightened, thinking they saw a ghost. 38 He said to them, “Why are you troubled, and why do doubts rise in your minds? 39 Look at my hands and my feet. It is I myself! Touch me and see; a ghost does not have flesh and bones, as you see I have.”
>
> 40 When he had said this, he showed them his hands and feet. 41 And while they still did not believe it because of joy and amazement, he asked them, “Do you have anything here to eat?” 42 They gave him a piece of broiled fish, 43 and he took it and ate it in their presence.
>
> 44 He said to them, “This is what I told you while I was still with you: Everything must be fulfilled that is written about me in the Law of Moses, the Prophets and the Psalms.”

My question is, Did Mary experienced or was given by God a "glorified body" while on earth?

I am looking for Catholic Church teaching or Church Father beliefs on Mary's glorified body that hinted similarity on Jesus resurrected body.

Answer (score 2):

> The dogma of the Assumption means that the Virgin Mary now experiences
>   in heaven that union of glorified body and soul which her son enjoys.
>   She is no disembodied spirit, but a complete human person, body and
>   soul, matter and spirit, reigning with Christ.
>
> Mary experienced bodily redemption before the rest of the Church.
>   [Source](https://www.ewtn.com/library/ANSWERS/IRRIRR.HTM)

From another source:

> Now God has willed that the Blessed Virgin Mary should be exempted
>   from this general rule. She, by an entirely unique privilege,
>   completely overcame sin by her Immaculate Conception, and as a result,
>   she was not subject to the law of remaining in the corruption of the
>   grave, and she did not have to wait until the end of time for the
>   redemption of her body. 
>   **As he kept you a virgin in childbirth, thus he has kept your body incorrupt in the tomb and has glorified it by his divine act of transferring it from the tomb.** [Source](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_p-xii_apc_19501101_munificentissimus-deus.html)

So it seems that her body was a normal mortal body but kept incorrupt in the tomb and got glorified during that process at the end of her life.

Comment: you did not mentioned directly if the glorified body was experienced on earth and similar to ressurected Jesus. The Holy Eucharist is the Key and I will try to link some reference to affirmed transformation to "spiritual body".Godbless

Comment: Do not know if I am wet behind the ears or not. But it seems to me that Mary did not have a glorified body here on earth. That privilege is for those in heaven. I do not think that she had an ordinary human body either. her body resemble perhaps that of Adam and Eve prior to the first fall.

Comment: @KenGraham that would mean Mary was not capable of experiencing a physical pain but that is highly doubtful since clearly, Jesus was able...(she needed to sleep, eat, drink to sustain her body alive which is a sign of a mortal body)

Comment: Pain could be experienced, but childbirth would be painless. Tradition has it that the birth of Jesus was painless for the Virgin Mary!

Comment: @KenGraham, she was protected from certain pains and obviously, the childbirth of Jesus was one of them

Comment: @Ken Graham please read CCC1000 on "transfiguration of our bodies thru reception of the Holy Eucharist" and the Fr.Stefano Gobbi's Blue Book "Marian Movement of Priests" has good information and revelation.Godbless

Answer (score 2):

Was Mary given a glorified or “spiritual body” like the resurrected body of Jesus while on earth? [The Perfection of our First Parents, According to St Thomas Aquinas](http://kolbecenter.org/perfection-first-parents-aquinas/)

The short answer is **no** on both counts!

Mary's body while on earth was similar to that of Adam and Eve prior the fall of the human race in the *Earthly Paradise*.

> Since Mary was preserved from Original Sin, it logically follows that she would not be subject to the consequences of that sin. Let us then contemplate how this is reflected in her virginal soul. No narrow-mindedness limited her intelligence, for hers was the most wise, penetrating, and enlightened intellect after that of Our Lord. No weakness impaired her will, the most vigorous and ardent will ever created. No selfishness restricted her heart, the most all-encompassing, generous, and caring heart ever known after that of her Son.
>
> This glory of her Immaculate Conception was reflected in her body. She did not experience the concupiscence that wreaks such havoc within us. Sickness did not harm her. Finally, unlike the rest of men, Our Lady was subject to neither pain nor bodily death. Nevertheless, God willed that she experience both suffering and death that she might know the same torments we suffer. With this store of shared experience, Our Lady’s compassion for us is all the more maternal and merciful.
>
> We have so far studied only a small part of this great mystery. The Almighty did much more than create Mary in a state of grace like that of the angels and our first parents. He graced her soul with the sum of all virtues to such an imminent degree that our minds cannot grasp its splendor. Theologians teach that from that first moment, the Blessed Virgin surpassed in perfection not only the highest angel, but all angels and saints put together. Her incomparable beauty is such that the Holy Ghost exclaims in admiration: “Thou art all beautiful, O my love, and there is no blemish in thee”—Tota pulchra es et macula non est in te. (Cant. 4:7). - [The Virgin Mary](http://www.tfp.org/virgin-mary/)

It seems that Mary did not have a glorified body here on earth. That privilege is for those in heaven. I do not think that she had an ordinary human body either. Her body resembled that of Adam and Eve prior to the first fall. Mary's body would be free from all sin and all manners of sin and diseases, while on earth. She could still suffer and fell sorrow before her assumption.

> The resurrected body is not spiritual by being made out of, or turned into, a spiritual substance. It is spiritual by being completely subject to the spirit (soul) of its possessor.
>
> But such is the disposition of a glorified body that it is spiritual, i.e. subject to the spirit, as the Apostle says (1 Cor. 15:44). Now in order for the body to be entirely subject to the spirit, it is necessary for the body's every action to be subject to the will of the spirit. Again, that an object be seen is due to the action of the visible object upon the sight, as the Philosopher shows (De Anima ii). Consequently, whoever has a glorified body has it in his power to be seen when he so wishes, and not to be seen when he does not wish it. (Summa Theologiae III, 54, 1 ad 2)
>
> For certain heretics, as Augustine relates (De Civ. Dei xiii, 22), ascribed to [glorified bodies] the subtlety whereby spiritual substances are said to be subtle: and they said that at the resurrection the body will be transformed into a spirit, and that for this reason the Apostle describes as being "spiritual" the bodies of those who rise again (1 Cor. 15:44). **But this cannot be maintained**. First, because a body cannot be changed into a spirit, since there is no community of matter between them. ... Hence others say that the aforesaid completeness by reason of which human bodies are said to be subtle will result from the dominion of the glorified soul (which is the form of the body) over the body, by reason of which dominion the glorified body is said to be "spiritual," as being wholly subject to the spirit."(Summa Theologiae Supplement, 83, 1) - [Thomistic Philosophy Page](http://www.aquinasonline.com/Questions/spiritbod.html)

Thus Mary's body prior to the Assumption was neither a spiritual body or a glorified body. After all her soul and body remained united while on earth and the need to maintain the body (eat) meant she still had an earthly, yet privileged body here below. A body cannot be changed into a spirit, since there is no community of matter between them. Mary needed to sleep, eat, drink to sustain her body alive which are signs of a mortal body. She did not possess a spiritual body which is the privilege of the Holy Angels.

> It is worth noting that the Virgin Mary has already received her glorified and resurrected body. Hence, she has the four gifts of the resurrection. - [Do You Know the Four Properties of a Glorified Resurrected Human Body?](http://taylormarshall.com/2012/10/do-you-know-four-properties-of.html)

Answer (score -2):

I will answer the question by qouting the CCC999 & CCC1000 on the word "spiritual body".

> 999 How? Christ is raised with his own body: "See my hands and my feet, that it >is I myself";553 but he did not return to an earthly life. So, in him, "all of >them will rise again with their own bodies which they now bear," but Christ >"will change our lowly body to be like his glorious body," into a "spiritual >body":554
>
> But someone will ask, "How are the dead raised? With what kind of body do they >come?" You foolish man! What you sow does not come to life unless it dies. And >what you sow is not the body which is to be, but a bare kernel. . . . What is >sown is perishable, what is raised is imperishable. . . . The dead will be >raised imperishable. . . . For this perishable nature must put on the >imperishable, and this mortal nature must put on immortality.555
>
> So from CCC999 clearly stated "," but Christ "will change our lowly body to be >like his glorious body," or into a "spiritual body"

Now did Mary as the Catholic Orthodox belief in Mary's Dormition, Mary did not suffers physical death as St.Augustine and Catholic Church upheld that Mary did not commit any actual sins.

Genesis3:15 point to this as God the Father declares "perrenial enmity" between the Woman & Satan.

**In CCC999 the Church is talking about Christ giving us a glorified body but CCC1000 teaches even further by saying a "Transfiguaration of our Bodies by receiving the Holy Eucharist"**

> 1000 This "how" exceeds our imagination and understanding; it is accessible >only to faith. Yet our participation in the Eucharist already gives us a >foretaste of Christ's transfiguration of our bodies:
>
> Just as bread that comes from the earth, after God's blessing has been invoked >upon it, is no longer ordinary bread, but Eucharist, formed of two things, the >one earthly and the other heavenly: so too our bodies, which partake of the >Eucharist, are no longer corruptible, but possess the hope of resurrection.556

Basing our understanding on the Church Teaching on CCC999 "glorified body" and CCC1000 saying by faith "thru reception of the Holy Eucharist" the faithful Catholics can experience incorruptibility as our faith in Holy Eucharist teaches.

This clearly manifested in all the incorruptible bodies of the Saints.

**So, to answer if Mary experienced or was given a "glorified or spiritual body" like the resurrected body of Jesus while on earth.**

**The answer is YES!** a*s it affirmed by Mary messages of internal locution to Fr.Stefano Gobbi's Blue Book Marian Movement of Priest.And by Catholic Church teaching in CCC1000 that by FAITH, the reception of the Holy Eucharist our bodies are sanctified to experience "transfiguration" by Jesus abiding presence in us.This biblical promised of Jesus is written in John6:53-55.*

**Also it's worth pondering the following statements:**

> 1. The saints provided numerous evidence of experiencing incorruptibility of >the flesh.
> 2. Enoch and Elijah was lifted up to heaven body and soul.Take note this two >Patriarchs never receive the Holy Eucharist but was still able to enter God's >Kingdom.
>    As we all know scriptures said "nothing defiled shall enter God's Kingdom.."
> 3. After the Christ Ascension the Apostles together with Mary was praying the >Novena for the Holy Spirit to come.
>    The Holy Eucharist is like Jesus giving His flesh & blood that comes from >Blessed Virgin Mary in the Sanctified & Glorified formed, as Catholic Church >teaches the Real Presence Jesus in the Holy Eucharist is present >body,blood,soul & divinity.
>    Now imagine when Mary receives from Her Immaculate Body the Holy Eucharist in >the hands of the Apostles probably St.Peter Celebrated the Holy Mass in the >Upper Room.

**Would Mary capable of receiving in Her Immaculate Body what the Catholic Church teaches in CCC1000 regarding "transfiguration"?**

> " This "how" exceeds our imagination and understanding; it is accessible only >to faith. Yet our participation in the Eucharist already gives us a foretaste >of Christ's transfiguration of our bodies:"

Mary is sinless and Mary lived a Trinitarian life of faith there's no obstacle for Mary to receive what Jesus Christ has promised in the Gospel of John.

> As Pope Benedict XVI said: “The transformation of the bread and the wine into >Christ’s Body and Blood, is in fact the principle of the divinization of >creation itself…When, in adoration, we look at the consecrated Host, the sign >of creation speaks to us. And so, we encounter the greatness of His gift…>Through >this gaze of adoration, he draws us toward Himself, within His >mystery, through which He wants to transform us as He transformed the Host” (Corpus Domini ’06).

**And from biblical references:**

> “Who can ascend the mountain of the Lord? Or who may stand in His holy place? >He whose hands are sinless, whose heart is clean. Who desires not what is >vain.” **(Ps.24:3).**
>
> “All of us, gazing on the Lord’s glory with unveiled faces, are being >transformed from glory to glory into His very image by their Lord who is the >Spirit.” **( 2 Cor.3:18).**
>
> This Blood of Christ is real drink (2), and, together with His Flesh, is food >for our eternal life. () Jesus promised the Eucharist in these words: "Amen, >amen, I say to you, unless you eat the Flesh of the Son of Man, and drink His >Blood, you shall not have life in you. He who eats My Flesh and drinks My Blood >has life everlasting and I will raise him up on the last day. For My Flesh is >food indeed, and My Blood is drink indeed. He who eats My Flesh, and drinks My >Blood, abides in Me and I in him." **(John 6:54-57).**

If St.Paul a great sinner exclaimed while on earth "it is no longer I who lived but Jesus", a proof of Jesus abiding presence for those who received the Holy Eucharist, what more can the Theotokos the Immaculate Mother who is sinless from the beginning and during Her earthly life?

> To affirmed that Mary received a ***"glorified body while on earth"*** the Blue >Book Marian Movement of Priests by Fr.Stefano Gobbi had a couple of passages >where Mary said God had given Her a "glorified body while on earth".
> ***(Marian Movement of Priests artcle#330 title"Mother of the Eucharist" p. >508-512 and article#107 p.143)***

Fr.Stefano Gobbi cause for sainthood was on process and the Blue Book "Marian Movement of Priests" contains Imprimatur and approval of St.John Paul II during his Pontificate.

For more info on Fr.Stefano Gobbi's Movement and messages and it's Church status please see the link;

http://www.mmp-usa.net/papal-blessing/

http://www.mmp-usa.net/history/ and homepage http://www.mmp-usa.net/

Godbless!

Comment: Regarding Gobbi: https://www.catholicdoors.com/isit/isit01.htm

Comment: @Grasper I am a Member of MMP and if we use the gift of prudence which one will you believe the view of Webmaster of catholicdoors Jonn Miller (unknown if a clergy or belong to christian denomination)alledging that Fr.Gobbi's messages contains error or the Papal Blessings of St.John Paul II the Great and the Imprimatur of 3 Cardinals • El Cardenal Bernardino Echeverria Ruiz, OFM
• Cardinal Daoud’s Imprimatur for Arabic Edition
• Cardinal Wu’s Imprimatur for Chinese Edition
http://www.mmp-usa.net/papal-blessing/ link:http://www.mmp-usa.net/papal-blessing/  http://www.mmp-usa.net/

Comment: Well, you can't deny the false prophesies even from a lay understanding. Also, you can't reference Gobbi's messages as a Catholic tradition or teaching and base the interpretations on a private locution. The Imprimatur is not a declaration of authenticity and Pope blessed many people.

Comment: @Grasper try to visit the history of MMP.Prudence and discernment will not lead you to doubt the Movement, The worldwide membership of the M.M.P. now numbers at least 400 cardinals and bishops, more than 100,000 priests, and millions of religious and faithful around the world. The laypersons figures is more and for me to believe a one man opinion over thousands of Clergy not to mentioned theologians,biblical scholars who were once attended Fr.Gobbi's talk on MMP, its a unprudent to believe catholicdoors accusations.link; http://www.mmp-usa.net/history/

Comment: @Grasper for you info on IMPRIMATUR meaning; Imprimatur is an official approval from the hierarchy of the Roman Catholic Church stating that a literary or similar work is totally free from error in all matters of faith and doctrine, and hence is acceptable reading for faithful Catholics. An imprimatur is not given lightly; it follows a thorough review process. Godbless

Comment: Catholics are obligated in faith to accept all general or public revelation, but they are not guilty of sin if they decline to believe in particular private revelations, even if those private revelations really occurred.

Comment: “And all the days of Henoch were three hundred and sixty-five years. And he walked with God, and was seen no more: because God took him.” (Genesis 5:23–24)“ And as they went on, walking and talking together, behold, a fiery chariot and fiery horses parted them both asunder: and Elias went up by a whirlwind into heaven.” (2 Kings 2:11) The two prophets  **Enoch and Elijah** did not die. According to St Thomas Aquinas, they are preserved in the atmospheric heaven (which is identified with earthly paradise), but not in the empyrean heaven (Heaven proper). See Summa theologiae III, q. 49, a. 5.

Comment: @Ken Graham Elijah was with Jesus in the Transfiguration (Matthew17:1-12).CCC1000 "foretaste of transfiguration", Pope BXVI "reflection on transformation" and Jesus "transfiguration" all points to "a foretaste of glorified & spiritual body". Blessed Duns Scotus philosophy applies to Mary's Transfiguration on Earth.Read the Immaculate Conception Dogma and reflect on Mary's priveleges was given always ahead because She was CHOSEN.Sanctifying grace & then "glorified body" was given ahead by the virtue of the merits won by Christ.Godbless